# "android:name" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: android, xml

I am getting this error when i am trying to implement heyzap sdk. I have no idea whats the problem. Here it is

```
<activity android:name = "com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapInterstitialActivity"   
    android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden | orientation | screenSize | smallestScreenSize" />

<activity android:name = "com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapVideoActivity" 
    android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden | orientation | screenSize | smallestScreenSize" />

<receiver android:name = "com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme = "package"/>
        <action android:name = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:407: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the XML that causes that problem, but there's another issue: You should remove the spaces around `|` in `configChanges`.

Comment: It doesnt has the space its somehow showing space here when i copy pasted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add spaces here /> so instead of

```
<data android:scheme = "package"/>
<action android:name = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
```

Should be

```
<data android:scheme = "package" />
<action android:name = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
```

This goes to all in your android manifest.